# Circular movement of player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a shark as player object which I am trying to control using a script, wherein when I press a key, the shark moves in the desired direction along with the animation.

The script works fine except when I use it for turning towards left side in circular motion. However the same doesn't give the desired movement as in the rotation is either clock wise or anti clock wise in the same circle.

What I am trying to do is when I press key for right side movement, the shark should move towards right side in circular motion from the last position. Here is the script.. Would appreciate any help here.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PredatorSphereScript : MonoBehaviour
{
private float m_moveSpeed = 50.0f;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
{

        if (Input.GetKey("j"))
        {
            moveLeft();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp("j"))
        {
            moveSlow();
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("l"))
        {
            moveRight();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp("l"))
        {
            moveSlow();
        }
     }


    public void moveLeft()
    {
         trtransform.Rotate (Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * -m_moveSpeed);
        {
            animation.CrossFade("SharkLT", 0.2f);
        }
    }

    public void moveRight()
    {
           transform.Rotate (Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * m_moveSpeed);
        {
            animation.CrossFade("SharkRT", 0.2f);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use the `transform.RotateAround` function instead? [Reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html). That way, you can make sure that the object is rotated around an axis that makes sense depending on whether you're turning left or right.

Comment: Also, you should really tag this post with "Unity3d", to attract more views.

Comment: Hi, transform.RotateAround works but then the position of the player (the shark) wont change and it rotates sideways. How do I make the player change the position in sync with flow of animation?

Comment: Well, it's a little hard to answer that, since I don't know how you have structured your GameObjects representing the shark, the animation, etc. You should edit your question with a more detailed explanation about which objects you have, and how they are related in the GameObject tree.